# how to use your password if you had change it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code that I'm using in logging in to my system. There's this function that I could change my password whenever I want. But the thing is, I don't know what to change in this code once my password has been changed so that I could use it in logging in.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if((usrnm.Text == "Administrator") && (password.Text == "administrator"))
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is Incorrect.");
    }
}
```

And also, everytime I changed it, it says that "Password has been changed" but it doesn't change in the database.

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (opw.Text == "administrator")
    {
        if (npw.Text == cpw.Text)
        {
            OpenDbase("Update USER set Password '" + this.npw.Text + "'");
            DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
            MessageBox.Show("Password has been changed.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Npw and Cpw mismatched.");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Opw was Incorrect.");
    }
}
```

Comment: First give me the clear details, which DB you are using and all. In the code which you have above, what is the use of DataTable you are using. And "OpenDbase" method is not given by you. Provide the full code or at least provide the necessary code

Comment: Is this the actual code, or is this a cut and paste error?  What I presume is your change password handler updates the password in a database, but in what I presume is your login handler you do this:  `if((usrnm.Text == "Administrator") && (password.Text == "administrator"))` no matter what the password is changed to, you always check that the password is `administrator`.

Comment: That code has two issues to begin with: On Login it does not check the current password but checks always for the same password. You'll need to compare the password against the password in the database. Same goes for the old password check for changing the password. Second: PLEASE NEVER EVER STORE PLAINTEXT PASSWORDS ANYWHERE!!! Hash them if you store them anywhere. Otherwise your clients could be in great trouble once the data gets stolen.

Comment: First **DON"T USE A PASSWORD**. WPF already knows the account of the current user. Use Windows authentication to connect to your database.

Comment: Second **DON'T WRITE YOUR OWN PASSWORD LOGIC**. It's already broken. Stealing cleartext passwords is trivial. Your code also leaves the application wide open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: For example, your code has a master password already. It's `' OR 1=1;--`. Type that, you'll be able to log with any account, because you concatenate strings to create queries. If you wanted to use your own logi, you should be *salting and hashing* the password using cryptographic algorithms suitable for passwords and use parameterized queries to look them up

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with your login code is, that it always compares the login password against a fixed string "administrator", not considering what the user changed the password to. You'll need to get the password for the current user before comparing anything. That in turn means that your DB needs to have a default value for the passwords.

If you want to support multiple users, something along those lines will work

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(CheckPassword(usrnm.Text, password.Text))
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is Incorrect.");
    }
}

private void btn_save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    if (CheckPassword(<usrnm.Text?>, opw.Text))
    {
        if (npw.Text == cpw.Text)
        {
            var salt = //Generate random string for salt
            OpenDbase("Update USER set Salt '" + salt + "'");
            OpenDbase("Update USER set Password '" + Hash(this.npw.Text, salt) + "'");
            DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
            MessageBox.Show("Password has been changed.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Npw and Cpw mismatched.");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Opw was Incorrect.");
    }
}

private bool CheckPassword(string user, string password){
    // Get Password hash & salt out of database
    var passwd = OpenDbase("SELECT Password FROM <???> WHERE USER=user");
    var salt = OpenDbase("SELECT Salt FROM <???> WHERE USER=user");

    if(/*No results found, i.e. user not in db*/){
        return false;
    } else {
        return passwd == Hash(password, salt);
    }
}

private string Hash(string text, string salt){
    // Apply e.g. SHA256 to the string and return the result
}
```

The code is only pseudo, the meat should be added by yourself. Two other issues with your code:

1. Never store plaintext passwords anywhere. Use hashing with a salt. I already wrote a dummy Hash-function in the correct places. Read up about it! It will prevent that a malicious thief will have all the passwords when he steals the data of your clients. Hashing alone will make your password unreadable, salting will prevent an easy search with so called rainbow tables which contain pre-computed hash values. Also, never write a hash function by yourself. Use what the framework already gives you. Again, read about Hashing & salting, some more info is in the comments. If it is a private project it is not *that* important, but still... please...
2. And you should absolutely parametrize your Query. Guess what happens if someone writes "abc'; DROP USERS;" as his new password? Right, it fucks up your database. You don't want that. Use parametrized queries if available, they will take care of problematic values for you.

**/!\** Also an Important thing to note; **not caring about this stuff can get your company and you personally in some serious legal trouble**

**Edit:** Some corrections based on the comments, so some comments won't make that much sense anymore... Thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: First, the real solution for sql injection is to use parameterized queries. Sanitization is just a hack that never works adequately. What would one sanitize here? The spaces? The words? The non-special characters like `;`, `'` and `-`? Besides, a password like `'; DROP TABLE PASSWORDS; --` would be perfectly safe a nice surprise for any script kiddie that somehow stole that password

Comment: Second, hashing isn't enough. You need salting, a cryptographically strong hashing algorithm *and* a few thousand repetitions. At least. Calculating weak hashes like MD5 is so fast one can use brute force to find the password that corresponds to a hash.

Comment: Finally, *don't* write your own hashing, especially for passwords. .NET already has the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) class that allows you to create a hash appropriate for passwords, specifying the number of hashing iterations. The default number of iterations is 1000. Troy Hunt explains this nicely in [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 7: Insecure Cryptographic Storage](https://www.troyhunt.com/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-7/)

Comment: Looking at the code, there are a lot of problems. `CheckPassword` doesn't work. It contains an **assignment**, not a comparison. It's insecure as it *loads* the "password" in memory. The `update` code still uses string concatenation and will still break if the hash contains characters like `'`. A single statement could update the database record, ie `UPDATE Users set Hash=@newhash where UserName=@user and hash=@oldHash`. The fields `Hash` field should be `binary` or `varbinary` to avoid the conversion to a string

Comment: ^ this. Far more knowledge than I have regarding the details. Salting was somewhere back in my mind, but I didn't think of it at the time. Also didn't know that sanitizing is not the "real" solution and parametrizing is better. For the hashing, of course I'd suggest to use ready made classes and not use some faulty implementations of your own, but I don't know them as I never worked with them. The comparision is indeed a typo...

Answer (score 0):

`(password.Text == "administrator")`

This always check with administrator

(`password.Text=="Data"` which your stored in Db related to that user")

You have to do it like this.